# Window.getComputedStyle does not show inline style

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have simple html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 594 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
            <rect id="rect" fill="#98df8a" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i use: `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('rect'))`, I get the value of both `width` and `height` to be `auto` and not `100px` like what I expected.

Is this how it should be? If so, how can i make it to return 100px ?

I need this function to turn all my styles defined in the external css into inline style attribute for svg elements so that I can export it later.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `document.getElementById('rect').style.height` and `document.getElementById('rect').style.width` and if you want to handle an arbitrary list of styles something like this:

```
var exportStyleKeys = ['width', 'height'];
var rect = document.getElementById('rect');
var exportStyles = exportStyleKeys.reduce((styles, styleKey) => {
  styles[styleKey] = rect.style[styleKey];
  return styles;
}, {});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oukzzx7w/)

Answer (score 0):

`window.document.getElementById('rect').style.width` will return you the inline css width attribute.

Try the blow code

```js
var rect = window.document.getElementById('rect');
console.log(rect.style.width);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 594 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
            <rect id="rect" fill="#98df8a" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```